# How can I tell if a Joda DateTime is, say, between the hours of 4-8pm?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'd like to check if a given DateTime is between 4am - 8am or between 12am-3am. What would be the right way to go about doing that?

This seems to do the trick:

```
        DateTime start  = new DateTime().withHourOfDay(4);
        DateTime end  = new DateTime().withHourOfDay(8);
        Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
        if(interval.contains(now)) return true;
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `getHourOfDay()`

```
int hour = new DateTime().getHourOfDay();
return ((hour >= 16) && (hour < 20))    //4-8pm
        || ((hour >= 0) && (hour < 3)); //12-3am
```

Comment: Why is this better?